# Objective-C inheritance, clarification needed

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have

```
@interface PlayerDeck : Deck
@interface MasterDeck : Deck
```

Both `PlayerDeck` and `MasterDeck` have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *cards;   // All cards in this Deck
```

Inside Deck' I'd like to

```
-(NSString*) descriptionOfDeck: (Deck *) deck
```

Inside both `PlayerDeck` and `MasterDeck` i'd like to

```
-(NSString*) description{
    [super descriptionOfDeck:self];
}
```

Inside Deck i will iterate over cards inside each individual Decks:

```
-(NSString*) descriptionOfDeck: (Deck *) deck {

    NSString *deckDescription = [[NSString alloc] init];

    for (Card *c in [deck cards]) {
        deckDescription = [deckDescription 
                 stringByAppendingString:[c description]];
    }

    return deckDescription;
}
```

**The problem: [deck cards] does not resolve.**

Please help me understand.

Comment: Looks like `cards` should be a property declared by `Deck`, with a dummy implementation. The subclasses can then override it with real ones, and the compiler will be content that `cards` is always safe to call on any kind of `Deck`.

Comment: @rgeorge, please respond with an "answer"

Comment: Or else, in `[deck cards]`, he needs to cast `deck` to a class or protocol that *does* implement `cards`.  A little flakier than having a strict hierarchy, but I've seen much flakier than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're saying the `cards` property is only defined on the `MasterDeck` and `PlayerDeck` classes, and *not* on `Deck`.

If that's correct, consider the type of `deck` when you attempt to send it the `cards` message: it is of type `Deck`, which doesn't define `cards`. You need to either cast it to a type which *does* define `cards`, or define `cards` in the base class directly. The latter seems more sensible, both for resolving this issue, and because it seems appropriate that all `Deck`s have cards!

**Update:** An example of casting in your case would be:

```c
for (Card *c in [((MasterDeck *) deck) cards])
```

But you can see the problem with that, can't you? It requires the base class to somehow know about its child classes, which sort of defeats the purpose of inheritance.

As I - and @rgeorge, in the comments - have suggested, declaring the `cards` property in the base class is the better move.

Comment: Would be correct to declare cards in Deck as a weak pointer: `@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *cards;` and skip `[[alloc] init]` as subclass will provide actual content, or should i initialize in super?

Comment: By logic, deck is the owner of the cards so it should'nt be a weak pointer. When you destroy the deck, deck cards should be destroyed, too. I think you are missing basic knowledge of Object oriented programming.